# How to create web reference manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, soap, soap-client

I know that I can point to some SOAP web service by adding web reference using visual studio.

But I need to do it from code.

How can I manually create web reference object in code and access all methods from that object?
Basically I want to avoid generating proxy classes.

Comment: _"Basically I want to avoid generating proxy classes"_ - **why**?

Comment: I can access to the service URL only from specific IP address. And that is production server address. I need to generate it in my local machine but can't.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a copy of the service contract (interface)([svcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can help with this) then you can include it in your project and use the ChannelFactory class to dynamically create a channel for the client to communicate with the service.

I tend to encapsulate it all up in a SAL (Service Application Layer) to re-use as required.

This is a simple (and in no way complete!) example demonstrating how to connect to a fictious time service and call the GetTime() operation without using a VS generated proxy:

```
public class TimeSAL : IDisposable
{
    private ChannelFactory<ITimeService> timeServiceProxyFactory;
    private ITimeService timeServiceProxy;

    private ITimeService TimeService
    {
        get
        {
            //create channel factory if not there
            if (timeServiceProxyFactory == null)
                timeServiceProxyFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITimeService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://url_to_my_timeservice_endpoint"));  //

            if (timeServiceProxy == null)
                timeServiceProxy = amlProxyFactory.CreateChannel();

            return timeServiceProxy;
        }

    }

    public string GetTime()
    {
        return TimeService.GetTime();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //dispose of ChannelFactory and proxy.
        //ensure you check for comm faults to abort before closing
    }

}
```

Now I can use this SAL throughout my code as necessary:

```
 ....
 using(TimeSAL timeSAL = new TimeSAL())
 {
   myBusinessObject.CurrentTime = timeSAL.GetTime();
 }
 ....
```

If you are unable to get your hands on a copy of the service contract, a long-winded way is to handcraft the soap request. Fiddler or soapUI can help with what the message should look like.

Hope some of this helps.